# JMETER - WebDriver Sampler - Groovy - Dynamic Name (3 Level)

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Thank you for your prompt responses. I have tried the below codes but looks like not picking up the values because there's 3 level of variables. Can you please advise? Thanks.

1st level: xpath=(//input[@type='text'])[7]

2nd level
it doesn't work:  //li[contains(@id, 'cascader-menu')]/span
or
it doesn't work: //li[contains(@id,'cascader-menu')]/span[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slW8u.png)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anyone is capable of coming up with a proper unique locator by looking at the screenshot without having access to full [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) or application

From what I can see so far you need the following element:

```
//input[@placeholder='Select...']
```

However it may or may not work depending on:

- whether there is another input element matching this query, if there are more than one - the action goes to the first match
- it is visible
- it can be interacted with (i.e. not covered by a modal window or not disabled)
- phase of the moon

You can test your expressions using your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and given you will get the match - Selenium will also be able to find the element and hopefully work with it.

If you going to continue repeatedly ignoring my suggestions of getting familiarized with DOM and XPath concepts I can only suggest recording the scenario using [Selenium IDE](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/) and hope that it could be replayed without modifications.